# binning data for group summaries

Tags: r

I am trying to analyze some data following an example provided on a DataCamp course. However, I think that they are skipping some steps on Datacamp and I am having some problems.
In particular, in the example that they provide they have a dataset called MedGPA that looks like this:

```
  Accept Acceptance Sex BCPM  GPA VR PS WS BS MCAT Apps
1       D          0   F 3.59 3.62 11  9  9  9   38    5
2       A          1   M 3.75 3.84 12 13  8 12   45    3
3       A          1   F 3.24 3.23  9 10  5  9   33   19
4       A          1   F 3.74 3.69 12 11  7 10   40    5
5       A          1   F 3.53 3.38  9 11  4 11   35   11
6       A          1   M 3.59 3.72 10  9  7 10   36    5
7       A          1   M 3.85 3.89 11 12  6 11   40    5
8       D          0   M 3.26 3.34 11 11  8  9   39    7
9       A          1   F 3.74 3.71  8 10  6 11   35    5
10      A          1   F 3.86 3.89  9  9  6 10   34   11
11      A          1   F 4.00 3.97 11  9  8 11   39    6
12      A          1   F 3.35 3.49 11  8  4  8   31    9
13      A          1   M 3.77 3.77  8 10  7 10   35    5
14      D          0   M 3.60 3.61  9  9  4 10   32    8
15      D          0   M 3.29 3.30 11  8  6  7   32   15
16      A          1   F 3.26 3.54 12  8  8 10   38    6
17      D          0   M 3.75 3.65  8  8  8 11   35    6
18      A          1   M 3.51 3.54  9 10  9 11   39    1
19      D          0   M 3.27 3.25  8  9  5 10   32    5
20      A          1   M 3.95 3.89 13 14  8 13   48    5
```

Then, they say that you should bin the data and run some analysis on the binned dataset.

They provide the binned dataset and it looks like this:

```
> MedGPA_binned
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  bin         mean_GPA acceptance_rate
  <fct>          <dbl>           <dbl>
1 [2.72,3.3]      3.11           0.2  
2 (3.3,3.44]      3.39           0.2  
3 (3.44,3.58]     3.54           0.75 
4 (3.58,3.7]      3.65           0.333
5 (3.7,3.87]      3.79           0.889
6 (3.87,3.97]     3.91           1
```

Where the GPA predicts whether the student will be accepted (acceptance_rate).

**How do I get from the first to the second dataset?**

In my dataset I have a series of answer to questions (continuous vars) and the variable I want to predict is CorrectGuess. This variable has only 2 possible outcomes: 0 = correct guess, 1 = wrong guess.

With my dataset I tried:

```
data$bins2 = cut(data$Q15_1, breaks = 4, labels = c("Level1", "Level2", "Level3","Level4"))
```

This adds a column to my dataset called bins2 that looks like

```
level2
leve1
leve3
level1
```

and so on...

I also tried a different way:

```
# Creating bins
# set up boundaries for intervals/bins
breaks <- c(0,20,40,60,80,100)
# specify interval/bin labels
labels <- c("<20", "20-40", "40-60", "60-80", "80-100")
# bucketing data points into bins
bins <- cut(data$Q15_1, breaks, include.lowest = T, right=FALSE, labels=labels)
# inspect bins
summary(bins)
plot(bins, main="Frequency", ylab="Ppt Answer Rating",col="bisque")
```

This creates a variable called bins but still doesn't look like what I need.

**HOW DO I CREATE A DATASET WITH THE BINNED DATA AND THE PROBABILITY OF CORRECT GUESS FOR EACH BIN?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer above is good. You can also use `dplyr` syntaxe to do what you want through  `group_by` and `summarise` functions.

```
  library(dplyr)

  df %>% group_by(bin = cut(GPA, breaks = c(2.72, 3.3, 3.44, 3.58, 3.7, 3.87, 3.97))) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(GPA), acceptance_rate = sum(Acceptance) / length(Acceptance))
```

With df is your dataset

```
 bin          mean acceptance_rate
  <fct>       <dbl>           <dbl>
1 (2.72,3.3]   3.26           0.333
2 (3.3,3.44]   3.36           0.5  
3 (3.44,3.58]  3.52           1    
4 (3.58,3.7]   3.64           0.25 
5 (3.7,3.87]   3.76           1    
6 (3.87,3.97]  3.91           1
```

Comment: Hi Remi, 
this also looks great. I tried it but it says:
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

I am sure that I am doing something wrong...

Comment: Hi Glu, i'm sorry I miss to add the package source

Comment: Sorry, I was trying it on my data and I made a stupid mistake. Thank you very much. It looks like it is working. I really appreciate =)

Comment: Thank you very much. Stats+R it is really a trip ^_^

Answer (score 2):

It does not make much sense to me to bin the data before performing a regression, you're just throwing away information, and possibly distorting the analysis.

But in any case, I believe something like this is what you're looking for, using `aggregate()`

```
tt <- read.table(text="
  Accept Acceptance Sex BCPM  GPA VR PS WS BS MCAT Apps
1       D          0   F 3.59 3.62 11  9  9  9   38    5
2       A          1   M 3.75 3.84 12 13  8 12   45    3
3       A          1   F 3.24 3.23  9 10  5  9   33   19
4       A          1   F 3.74 3.69 12 11  7 10   40    5
5       A          1   F 3.53 3.38  9 11  4 11   35   11
6       A          1   M 3.59 3.72 10  9  7 10   36    5
7       A          1   M 3.85 3.89 11 12  6 11   40    5
8       D          0   M 3.26 3.34 11 11  8  9   39    7
9       A          1   F 3.74 3.71  8 10  6 11   35    5
10      A          1   F 3.86 3.89  9  9  6 10   34   11
11      A          1   F 4.00 3.97 11  9  8 11   39    6
12      A          1   F 3.35 3.49 11  8  4  8   31    9
13      A          1   M 3.77 3.77  8 10  7 10   35    5
14      D          0   M 3.60 3.61  9  9  4 10   32    8
15      D          0   M 3.29 3.30 11  8  6  7   32   15
16      A          1   F 3.26 3.54 12  8  8 10   38    6
17      D          0   M 3.75 3.65  8  8  8 11   35    6
18      A          1   M 3.51 3.54  9 10  9 11   39    1
19      D          0   M 3.27 3.25  8  9  5 10   32    5
20      A          1   M 3.95 3.89 13 14  8 13   48    5", header=TRUE)

tt$BCPMd = cut(tt$BCPM, breaks=4, labels=c("L1", "L2", "L3","L4"))
aggregate(cbind(GPA, Acceptance) ~ BCPMd, data=tt, mean)
#   BCPMd      GPA Acceptance
# 1    L1 3.358333        0.5
# 2    L2 3.574000        0.6
# 3    L3 3.732000        0.8
# 4    L4 3.910000        1.0
```

Comment: Hi AkselA, thank you so much for your answer.
This looks great. I only have a question: in aggregate, you calculate the mean acceptance by the binned BCPMd if I understand. Is that correct?
In that case, is mean acceptance the same as the probability of occurrence? Because the next step would be to calculate the odds, starting from the rate of acceptance by doing something like:
# compute odds for bins
MedGPA_binned <- MedGPA_binned %>%
  mutate(odds = acceptance_rate / (1 - acceptance_rate)).

Comment: Also, I have tried calculating a model on my data:
mod = glm(CorrGuess ~ Q15_1, data = data, family = binomial). But apparently for logistic regression, a good step is to bin the data and then fit the model on the binned data. That's what I am getting by following the steps on datacamp

Comment: Yes, mean acceptance is the same as probability of acceptance. Your goal is to predict acceptance based on these other variables, I assume? If so there is no point in regressing on binned data. Binning and summarizing like we've done here is useful in an exploratory capacity, but not for statistical inference. Of course it's up to you to choose your method, just fair warning.

Comment: If you are binning the data to deal with nonlinearities, then there are better methods for that.

Comment: Hello Aksel, I really appreciate your comment. Yes, the goal is to predict acceptance based on the other variables. As mentioned, I am just following step by step a tutorial on DataCamp for logistic regression. If I understand what they say, the problem is how to konw whether the model is accurate. Since our actual observations are all 0 and 1 but the predicted observations are all BETWEEN 0 and 1, you will always be off some amount. For these data, you get that 27 years old have 50% survival chances. A way of addressing this problem is to bin the data...

Comment: By binning these data, it becomes clear that survival chances decrease with age.
Again, this is what they suggest with their example. They also say that we can do 3 things: use bins, use odds scale or use the log-odds scale. However, interpreting the model is quite difficult for one reason or another.

ANYWAYS: can you suggest me some online tutorial for doing what you suggest possibly with some R code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `glm(..., family=binomial)` uses logit link function by default, so you're already estimating log odds, not probabilities. [UCLA-IDRIE](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/) has some nice tutorials.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like the formula I was using. On my own data I am trying:
mod = glm(CorrGuess ~ Q15_1, data = data, family = binomial). 
Q15_1 would be question 15. Do you mind if I ask another question? The questions I have are like: Q15: How much attention where you paying to A? Q16: how much attention where you paying to B?
So, I think I have a factor, call it ATTENTION, with two levels, A and B.
All the examples I am seeing for logistic regressions use predictors with 1 level.
In the example above, you just have mean_gpa, no levels. Can I use logistic reg in this case and how?

Comment: It sounds like those variables are binary, which should pose no problem. If there were were multiple ordered levels, as in a Likert scale, you'd have to be a bit more careful. Are you familiar with these [terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement)? This is getting a bit beyond the scope of comments, but you should read up on why we use different error distributions, like normal, binomial and poisson, what the link function does, what assumptions we use, what happens when we break them, how can we generalize so we don't break them. GLM is already a generalization of LM, how/why?